# Can we recursively enumerate every type in type theory?

Tags: type-theory

Can we answer the question: "What are all the types?" i.e. can we recursively generate all the types in a given type theory according to a certain set of rules? Pardon for asking such a weird question.

**Question/personal background**: I'm leaving this question intentionally vague with regards to what I mean by "type theory" because I guess I'm just interested in the status of this question for type theories in general. My background is pure math and I am comfortable with proofs in ZFC and FOL but I can't write a single line of code in any programming language. I hope to understandthe basics of using type theory for proof like Lean does, and started reading about type theory yesterday in preparation, although I've heard snippets about type theory in passing elsewhere.

Comment: If I make my choice of what you mean by "type theories in general" and interpret "type" to mean a bit of syntax that denotes a type, then you can recursively generate all the types in a given type theory, because that's just a question of enumerating syntax. I think it is now down to you to tie down what you actually want to know.